# Generate Truth Tables with some variables already set in python

Tags: python

My requirement is to generate the truth tables for n variables, for which i can use itertables. However, in this requirement I have some variables already set to True/False
For eg sample input is [True, False, Undefined, True, Undefined]

What I want to generate is

```
[True, False, True, True, True]
[True, False, True, True, False]
[True, False, False, True, True]
[True, False, False, True, False]
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; we simply need to construct a list with all the options we're choosing from for each element.  For example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> vv = [True, False, None, True, None]
>>> choose_from = [[True, False] if x is None else [x] for x in vv]
>>> pp = product(*choose_from)
>>> for p in pp:
...     print(p)
...     
(True, False, True, True, True)
(True, False, True, True, False)
(True, False, False, True, True)
(True, False, False, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of lists like this:

```
possible = [[True],[False],[True,False],[True],[True,False]]
```

Then use `itertools.product`:

```
for table in itertools.product(*possible):
     ....
```